# Left join Ignore

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

I have recently noticed that SQL Server 2016 appears to be ignoring left joins if any column is not used in the `select` or `where` clause. Also not found in Actual execution plan.

This is good for if anyone added extra join but still not affecting performance.

I have query that took 9 sec, if I add column in select clause for Left join tables but without that only 1 sec.

Can anyone please check and suggest, Is that true or not?

Query with Actual execution plan. You can see there is no any table from left join in execution plan.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't seem to make much sense (possibly a language barrier). Can you please try to explain your query a little more please? What are you wanting us to check here exactly? You mention a query, but there's no query in your question, so how can we comment on that without it? You might want to provide the query plan as well. [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: That is correct, execution engine ignores the table in such case.

Comment: Please add some sample data, would be easier to answer your question

Comment: 2008R2 also performs the optimization where it can.

Comment: Why are you asking when you've seen the exection plan? If you observe it happening, it's clearly something the optimizer can do.

Comment: Slightly off topic but you might want to read about NOLOCK before you continue slapping that hint on every query. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ It is far more sinister than most people realize.

Comment: Thank you but I need NOLOCK and know about that.

Comment: Hi. You are not clear. Use enough words to say what you mean. Also please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure what the question is asking, but a SQL optimizer can ignore `left join`.  Consider this type of query:

```
select a.*
from a left join
     b 
     on a.b_id = b.id;
```

If `b.id` is declared as `unique` (or equivalently a `primary key`) then the above query returns exactly the same result set as:

```
select a.*
from a;
```

I am not *per se* aware that SQL Server started putting this optimization in 2016.  But the optimization is perfectly valid and (I believe) other optimizers do implement it.

Remember, SQL is a *declarative* language, not a *procedural* language.  The SQL query describes the result set, not how it is produced.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am facing performance issue and while working on that found this. I became eager to know about this but not found anything in google. So I just asked here.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a left join and your matching condition don't return any data from the joined table it will return data as inner join return, when select statement does not contains columns from right tables. Not only in ms server 2016 but most of the DB's.

Left join reduces the performance of the query if there are large amount of data available in join tables.